# Как можно конвертировать "padding" в padding в миксинах scss?

Tags: sass, scss

Разбираюсь с миксинами. Как я понял я могу передать туда переменную и что-то с ней сделать:

```
$var: "padding"
@mixin exemple($var){
...
}
```

А можно ли сделать вызов такого миксина `@include exemple("padding")`и делать что-то со свойством `padding`? В scss тоже можно передавать переменным значение по умолчанию как в `js`? То есть, если написать:

```
@mixin exemple($var: "padding"){
$var: 20px;
}
```

то в `$var` при подключении миксина по идее можно будет передать любую строку. Есть ли способ конвертировать эту строку в свойство?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что, я хочу реализовать подходит [интерполяция](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/sassscript/interpolyatsiya/). Записывается как `#{}`, то есть если написать такой миксин:

```
@mixin exemple ($property){
#{$property}: 20px;
}
```

И использовать его так:

```
body{
@include exemple("margin");
}
```

То `body` добавится свойство `margin: 20px`. Естественно, использовать интерполяцию можно и в более сложных миксинах.